# Laravel Join on Null

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

As the title says, how do I join on a null condition in Laravel? Take the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 a 
 INNER JOIN TABLE2 b
  ON a.col1 = b.col1 
     OR a.col2 IS NULL
```

I've tried this but not the result I wanted:

```
$query = Table1::join('table2', function($join){
    $join->on('table1.col1', '=', 'table2.col1');
    $join->on('table1.col2', ????????);
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use `DB::raw` in the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use where inside [JoinClause](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/JoinClause.html) class, see [advanced join clause](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#advanced-join-clauses):

```
$query = Table1::join('table2', function($join){
    $join->on('table1.col1', '=', 'table2.col1')
    ->orWhereNull('table1.col2');
});
```